# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem to figure out why this error is occurring.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cid 
  FROM customers c
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT t.aid 
                  FROM transactions t
                 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT a.balance 
                                  FROM accounts a 
                                 WHERE t.cid = c.cid
                                   AND a.aid = t.aid
                                   AND ((sysdate - a.date_opened) > 365)
                                 ORDER BY a.balance DESC
                               )
              );
```

The error is in the last line.

Comment: Looks to be because your `ORDER BY` is inside the inner `EXISTS()`. Move the `ORDER BY` to the top level.

Comment: ORDER BY clause in sub queries is of not much use and only adds to execution time and so is not allowed.

Comment: I did not know it was not allowed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1. You can't reference table from subquery which is not a direct parent level — a subquery inside `EXISTS` does not see a table `c`, so condition `t.cid = c.cid` is wrong
2. I don't see any meaning in `ORDER BY` inside `EXISTS` subquery. It also can be illegal, but I'm not sure.

I advise you to rewrite query from 2 `EXISTS` into 2 `JOINS`. It would be like:

```
SELECT cid 
  FROM (SELECT c.cid, a.balance
          FROM customers c,
               accounts a,
               transactions t 
         WHERE t.cid = c.cid
           AND a.aid = t.aid
           AND sysdate - a.date_opened > 365)
 ORDER BY balance DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing mistake in **AND ((sysdate - a.date_opened) > 365)**

use like this :-

**AND (sysdate - a.date_opened) > 365**

Answer (score 0):

Side note: Your subquery is going to require a full table scan on `accounts`, even if you have an index on `date_opened`, because you are doing math in the WHERE clause.

For every row, Oracle has to evaluate this expression:

```
((sysdate - a.date_opened) > 365)
```

to take the value of `sysdate` and subtract the date opened and then compare it to 365.  It has to check each row individually.

However, if you algebraically change that expression to

```
sysdate - 365 > a.date_opened
```

then it only has to evaluate the expression `sysdate-365` once, at the beginning of the query, and can then compare that to `a.date_opened` and use the index for an index scan.